# Best practice for create web project in Eclipse/STS that supports maven and spring 3+

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, maven-3

I recently completed the SpringCore training but never got this answer.  I want to know the best possible way to create Dynamic Web Project in STS/Eclipse that supports Maven and Spring 3+

Is it to use the wizard and create a Dynamic Web Project then add Maven support and Spring Behavior?
Is it to use the wizard and create a Maven project and use archetype webapp then add Spring support?
Is it to use the wizard and create a Spring project add the Java EE project facet and Maven Support?
Is it something totally different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose to create first dynamic web project, then add spring behavior and finally to build the project i am using maven.. which is really a powerfull tool.

Comment: Did you just add the Maven behavior to the project?

Comment: No .. u just need to specify the pom file in your project.. then u need to build it with mvn command.. all dependency must be specified in the pom file..

Comment: [link]http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/ u can go to this link for complete tutorial..